# Determining if a device is a touchscreen device in linux

Tags: linux, char, device, device-driver, touchscreen

I am trying to determine what /dev/input/eventX device is the touchScreen.  I am currently looking at the return of EVIOCGNAME to get device name.  Looking at the return values of the  EVIOCGBIT ioctl I don't think there is a generic way to determine what is the touchscreen. I am interested in any sort of solution to this problem.  Thanks in advance for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

- /dev/input/by-path/
- /dev/input/by-id/
- /sys/class/input/event?/device/

These might have enough info for your needs. Wish I had a touchscreen to test ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the mask returned by `ioctl(EV_ABS)` contains `ABS_PRESSURE`, and `ioctl(EV_KEY)` contains `BTN_TOOL_FINGER`, then it's probably a touchscreen.