# How do I discover the ACPI id for a laptop touchpad in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, acpi, linux

How do I get the device ID for my touchpad in Linux? The device doesn't show up in `lspci`, `lsusb`, or `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`. For example, this patch adds the ID "ELAN0608": https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/8/10/145

I have a similar touchpad but I'm not sure what the ID is - it may need a change in the kernel. How do kernel developers go about querying info like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795544/determining-if-a-device-is-a-touchscreen-device-in-linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, well I emailed the author of that patch and it turns out that info is found with udev, using the command: `udevadm info -e`

Comment: What do you look for in that (extensive) output?

Comment: I piped it to less and searched for "touchpad", so: `udevadm info -e|less`, then `/ouchpad` or something like that, since it may or may not be capitalized.